# Changing a filename before downloading / saving it

Tags: files, downloads

I am trying to figure out a way to change a filename before it is saved to my `Downloads` folder. However, I can't seem to find any way to do this.

For example, before I save this file which I am downloading, I would like to change its name:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried in browser a right click on file to download >  Save link as..

Comment: @doug wow for some reason that didn't occur to me thank you! I was so used to Windows giving me the option to change the filename when I just clicked on it that I didn't even think of this

Answer (score 3):

Firefox has an option for change name before downloading:

Click <kbd>≡</kbd> → *Preferences* → *Downloads* → *Always ask you where to save files*

If you want to choose Downloads directory is default, just choose it and only that directory in the next time.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I tried this now but it still does not ask me where to save the file. I am downloading a file from my email (gmail) so would the issue still be about Firefox?

Comment: I downloaded file in gmail by Firefox too, It worked: [downloading](https://imgur.com/M5VmO2o)  `Firefox version 72.0.1`

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it by resizing the download window smaller.  For some strange reason it had kind-of "maximised" and cut off the top of the download window.

Answer (score 1):

You can save file with custom name while downloading it using `wget`.

```
wget -O example <URL of file>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more about **Firefox** question and not Ubuntu question.

Firefox allow that option ONLY if you use: *"Save Link As..."*, otherwise it's not possible.  I'm also not sure about Chrome, since that you need to find a browser that support in this option.